# How to create Login Page in Asp .net Core 1.0 and Entity Framework Core 1.0 (PostgreSql )

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I started learning Dot Net core 1.0.

Can anyone help me creating simple login page using core 1.0 with Postgresql

Comment: Please check this first - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve